# Need help identifying how to edit a div in mediawiki

Tags: javascript, php, css, mediawiki

Here is my website: http://www.stnwiki.com/wiki/

The tabs above the 'body' are what I wish to be able to change but I have tried and failed to locate where the css for them is..

http://prntscr.com/5198o9 Here is a picture highlighting 2 of the tabs.

I assume it can be found out using Google Chrome's inspect element, however I am not very clued in on how to use it.

However I may be totally wrong! Please let me know if you guys need other info!

Cheers,
Ollie

content of load.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is the entry point for the resource loader.
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
 * with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 * http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 *
 * @file
 * @author Roan Kattouw
 * @author Trevor Parscal
 */

// Bail if PHP is too low
if ( !function_exists( 'version_compare' ) || version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3.2' ) < 0 ) {
    // We need to use dirname( __FILE__ ) here cause __DIR__ is PHP5.3+
    require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/PHPVersionError.php';
    wfPHPVersionError( 'load.php' );
}

require __DIR__ . '/includes/WebStart.php';

wfProfileIn( 'load.php' );

// URL safety checks
if ( !$wgRequest->checkUrlExtension() ) {
    return;
}

// Respond to resource loading request
$resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
$resourceLoader->respond( new ResourceLoaderContext( $resourceLoader, $wgRequest ) );

wfProfileOut( 'load.php' );
wfLogProfilingData();

// Shut down the database.  foo()->bar() syntax is not supported in PHP4, and this file
// needs to *parse* in PHP4, although we'll never get down here to worry about = vs =&
$lb = wfGetLBFactory();
$lb->shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki loads CSS via [ResourceLoader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) from many sources, you don't need to know where the CSS comes from.

Your CSS modifications must be separated from the MediaWiki code. If that's the only change you need to make, an edit to the [[MediaWiki:Common.css]] page is probably all you need. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skin_configuration#Site-wide_CSS_modifications for more information and links.

Answer (score 0):

The styling for that div appears to be an inline style in a file called `load.php` (I used Google Chrome's inspect element).

If you right-click on a tab and click Inspect Element, it will open up a pane on the bottom. On the right pane will list all the styling on that element divided into sections, and on the right side of each section will tell you the file that those styles are in. If you click on that file name it will take you to the line where those styles are located inside that file.

Give it a try!

EDIT: The URL being executed for that style is http://www.stnwiki.com/wiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%7Cmediawiki.ui.button%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector&*, But I don't know what css file it is loading. I suggest looking at the MediaWiki documentation to find out.

Also, is there any way for you to define custom CSS in the admin panel of MediaWiki? If so, you can just use the class names of the tabs and override some of the styles.

Comment: I have added the contents of load.php to my question for you